# Updating HTML element's content during script execution in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I'm writing simple Sudoku solver as an exercise and I've thought that I will show entire process by displaying it step by step on 9x9 grid.

I'm using HTML table with nested divs for displaying game board (probably not relevant) and recursive function for solving preseeded Sudoku. My solution is in "spaghetti" state right now, so below I give you pseudocode for what I have:

```
function fillBoard() {
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      const cell = document.querySelector(`div[data-row="${i}"][data-column="${j}"]`);
      cell.innerHTML = gameState.solution[i][j];
    }
  }
}

function solve(row, column) {
  /* simplified, it's working :) */
  for(let guess = 1; guess < 10; guess++) {
    this.solution[row][column] = guess; <--- SHOW THIS STEP TO USER
    let conflicts = checkConflicts(row, column)           
    if(!conflicts) {
      let emptyCell = this.findNextEmptyCell(row, column);
      if(emptyCell) {
        let result = this.solve(emptyCell.i, emptyCell.j);
        if(!result) continue;
        else return true;
      }
      return true;
    }            
    else continue;
  }
}
```

I've tried putting `fillBoard()` function call inside `solve()` but that obviously didn't worked as I'm getting only the final result in form of solved grid. I've also tried using `setInterval(fillBoard, 100)` but `solve()` function is executing too fast.

How can I achieve "incremental" displaying of entire solving process by updating HTML after each `solve()` call?

I'm trying to get something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChjQRIhH414 but I'm filling the board left-right, top-bottom

Current solution: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJmVZw)

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you want here

Comment: @Liam I want to render HTML after each `solve()` function call, so user can see how this process is going, cell after cell, with backtracking to previous steps if solution is incorrect. Maybe I will be able to find an example working this way :)

Comment: So why don't you render "the HTML" after each solve call? It's not clear what exactly your stuck on here. Also what does any of this have to do with async? There are no async calls in this code?

Comment: I've added Codepen link to my question

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to slow down your html rendering process, which suggests animation to me. You can look into this approach, and maybe throttle it if you want. Without having a complete example I can't run it to be sure. I'll give you some pseudo code in response for the way I would test it to start with, and hopefully that'll point you in the right direction:

```
function fillBoard(i=0, j=0) {
  const cell = document.querySelector(`div[data-row="${i}"][data-column="${j}"]`);
  cell.innerHTML = gameState.solution[i][j];

  j++;
  if( j >= 9) { j = 0; i++; }
  if(i < 9)
  requestAnimationFrame(function() { fillBoard(i,j) });
}
```

If you want, you can replace requestAnimationFrame with a setTimeout on a given delay. You can set it to 1-2 seconds or something to start with to see if it gives you the results you're looking for.

Comment: if I understand correctly, this will show the final solution cell by cell? what I want to achieve is a bit different - to show entire solving process, I edited my code snippet to show a place where I want to render HTML. Thanks for reply :)

Comment: Yeah I see what you wanted now. Showing to the user is writing to html. You can create and call another method to write that out where you put your comment. You're still going to need to throttle your method somewhere so it doesn't display too fast.

Comment: It may actually be easier to save all the steps in a state/object and then play back through them in order instead of trying to render when you're solving. It'll definitely keep the code from getting out of control.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this approach, but it seems to be working pretty well. I will add an answer with working example

Answer (score 0):

Unoptimized, but working example, by following @loctrice advice from comments above. Still looking for other solutions to this problem.

```js
console.clear();

let states = [];
let x = 0;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const start = document.getElementById("start");
  const check = document.getElementById("check");
  const sudoku = document.getElementById("sudoku");

  function fillBoard(index) {
    console.log(`Displaying ${index}/${states.length}`);
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        const cell = document.querySelector(
          `div[data-row="${i}"][data-column="${j}"]`
        );
        cell.innerHTML =
          states[index][i][j] == 0 ? "" : states[index][i][j];        
      }
    }
  }

  class Sudoku {
    checkRow(row) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let number = this.solution[row][i];
        if (!number) continue;

        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
          if (i == j) continue;
          const challenge = this.solution[row][j];
          if (number == challenge) return number;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    checkColumn(column) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        let number = this.solution[i][column];
        if (!number) continue;

        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
          if (i == j) continue;
          const challenge = this.solution[j][column];
          if (number == challenge) return number;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    checkBox(box) {
      const rowModifier = Math.floor(box / 3) * 3;
      const colModifier = (box % 3) * 3;
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          let number = this.solution[i + rowModifier][j + colModifier];
          if (!number) continue;

          for (let x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
              if (x == i && y == j) continue;
              const challenge = this.solution[x + rowModifier][y + colModifier];
              if (number == challenge) return number;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    solve(row, column, array) {
      for (let guess = 1; guess < 11; guess++) {
        if (guess == 10) {
          this.solution[row][column] = 0;
          return false;
        }
        this.solution[row][column] = guess; // <=== SHOW ENTIRE BOARD HERE
        let state = this.solution.map(a => [...a]);
        array.push(state);
        const rowError = this.checkRow(row);
        const columnError = this.checkColumn(column);
        const boxError = this.checkBox(
          3 * Math.floor(row / 3) + Math.floor(column / 3)
        );
        if (!rowError && !columnError && !boxError) {
          // find next empty cell
          let emptyCell = this.findNextEmptyCell(row, column);
          if (emptyCell) {
            let result = this.solve(emptyCell.i, emptyCell.j, array);
            if (!result) continue;
            else return true;
          }
          return true;
        } else continue;
      }
    }

    findNextEmptyCell(row, column) {
      for (let i = row; i < 9; i++) {
        if (column == 8) column = 0;
        for (let j = column; j < 9; j++) {
          if (this.solution[i][j]) continue;
          else return { i: i, j: j };
        }
        column = 0;
      }
      return false;
    }

    generateBox(boxNumber) {
      let numbers = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        numbers.push(i);
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          const length = numbers.length;
          const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
          const number = numbers.splice(index, 1);
          const row = i + boxNumber * 3 / 4;
          const col = j + boxNumber * 3 / 4;
          this.solution[row][col] = parseInt(number) + 1;
        }
      }
    }

    initialize() {
      this.solution = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        this.solution.push([]);
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
          this.solution[i][j] = 0;
        }
      }

      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.generateBox(i * 4);
      }
    }
  }

  let gameState = new Sudoku();
  gameState.initialize();
  
  start.onclick = function() {
    gameState.solve(0, 3, states);
    window.setInterval(function() {if(x < states.length) fillBoard(x++);}, 15);
  };

  check.onclick = function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      let error = gameState.checkRow(i);
      if (error) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
          const cell = document.querySelector(
            `div[data-row="${i}"][data-column="${j}"]`
          );
          cell.classList.add("incorrect-area");
          if (cell.innerHTML == error) cell.classList.add("incorrect");
        }
        return;
      }

      error = gameState.checkColumn(i);
      if (error) {
        const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-column="${i}"]`);
        cells.forEach(c => {
          c.classList.add("incorrect-area");
          if (c.innerHTML == error) c.classList.add("incorrect");
        });
        return;
      }

      error = gameState.checkBox(i);
      if (error) {
        const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-box="${i}"]`);
        cells.forEach(c => {
          c.classList.add("incorrect-area");
          if (c.innerHTML == error) c.classList.add("incorrect");
        });
        return;
      }
    }
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr");
    row.classList.add("row");

    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      let td = document.createElement("td");
      let cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.classList.add("cell");

      cell.dataset.row = i;
      cell.dataset.column = j;

      let a = Math.floor(i / 3);
      let b = Math.floor(j / 3);
      cell.dataset.box = 3 * a + b;

      cell.innerHTML =
        gameState.solution[i][j] == "0" ? "" : gameState.solution[i][j];

      if (!cell.innerHTML)
        cell.onclick = function(e) {
          const row = e.target.dataset.row;
          const col = e.target.dataset.column;

          gameState.solution[row][col] =
            ++gameState.solution[row][col] > 9
              ? 0
              : gameState.solution[row][col];
          cell.innerHTML =
            gameState.solution[row][col] == "0"
              ? ""
              : gameState.solution[row][col];

          document
            .querySelectorAll("div.cell")
            .forEach(c =>
              c.classList.remove("correct", "incorrect", "incorrect-area")
            );
        };

      td.appendChild(cell);
      row.appendChild(td);
    }

    sudoku.appendChild(row);
  }
});
```

```css
.incorrect-area {
    background-color: #A55 !important;
    border-color: #F00 !important;
}

.correct {
    background-color: #1A1 !important;
    border-color: #0F0 !important;
}

.incorrect {
    background-color: #A11 !important;
    border-color: #F00 !important;
}

div[data-box='1'], 
div[data-box='3'], 
div[data-box='5'], 
div[data-box='7'] {
    background-color: #444;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    min-height: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 32px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#buttons {
    text-align: center;
}

div {
    padding: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #000;
}

#game {
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

#sudoku {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #111;
    border: dashed 1px white;
    color: white;
}

.row {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.cell {
    cursor: default;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: solid white 1px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    user-select: none;
}

.cell:hover {
    background-color: #765;
    transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SudoQ</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="game">
        <div id="buttons">
            <div id="start" class="button">SOLVE</div>
            <div id="check" class="button">CHECK</div>
        </div>
        <table id="sudoku">
        </table>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```